# How can I cast variables in matlab with fixed floating point

Tags: matlab

Is it possible convert a double variable to a float (single in Matlab) with fixed floating point?
For example

> x = 10.023213032130123021302130210331232132103312321

to

> x = 10.0231

Thank you !

Comment: Isn't "fixed floating point" a contradiction in terms?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is more accurate if you say : "choose the number of the digits that you want to represent a float"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I round to a certain floating-point precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990408/roundig-up-to-a-certain-floating-point-matlab)

Comment: Since there are no "float11" which would give the right number of decimals, but only double and single classes, "cast" is not the right word here. When you cast a variable you convert it from one class to another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert to `single`:

```
X = single(Y)
```

And than apply `round()` to get fixed format:

```
X = round(10^N*X) / 10^N;
```

to get N digits behind the decimal point